# Reuse DB adapter on bootstrap to set custom handler DB session in Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, database-connection

In **bootstrap**:

```
public function _initSession()
{
    $config = Zend_Registry::get('config'); // application.ini
    $params = $config->default->resources->db->params->toArray();
    $db = Zend_Db::factory($config->default->resources->db->adapter, $params);
    Zend_Db_Table_Abstract::setDefaultAdapter($db);

    $config = array(
        'name'           => 'session',
        'primary'        => 'id',
        'modifiedColumn' => 'modified',
        'dataColumn'     => 'data',
        'lifetimeColumn' => 'lifetime'
    );

    Zend_Session::setSaveHandler(
      new Cokidoo_Session_HandlerCache(
        new Cokidoo_Session_HandlerDb($config)));
 }
```

In **application.ini**:

```
default.resources.db.adapter = "PDO_MYSQL"
default.resources.db.params.username = myuser
default.resources.db.params.password = mypasss
default.resources.db.params.host = myhost
default.resources.db.params.dbname = mydbname
default.resources.db.params.driver_options.1002 = "SET NAMES utf8"
```

I am setting custom handler to store sessions in MySQL. For doing that, I need to set the default adapter to database connection. By doing this, I create a database connection. But I realized that afterwards, Zend creates a new connection in the call

```
Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->_ connect
```

Therefore, it is creating a database connection twice. That happens in every request to our web app so I want to avoid this becouse it is a performance issue.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to create default adapter just before session handler try do `$this->bootstrap('db');` I guess it will be enough for initializing db connection once.

Comment: Thanks! Also had to remove 'default.' from resources in application.ini